Find a partition of rows to satisfy the Ghouila-Houri criterion for total unimodularity
I'm trying to determine whether a given matrix is totally unimodular by verifying the Ghouila-Houri criterion. The criterion states that a matrix is totally unimodular if and only if we can partition the rows into two sets, ( R_1 ) and ( R_2 ), such that for each column, the difference between the sum of entries in ( R_1 ) and the sum of entries in ( R_2 ) is in ( {-1, 0, 1} ).
Given the matrix:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Is it possible to find such a partition of rows to satisfy the Ghouila-Houri criterion?
If a partition exists, could you suggest how to find it or provide an example of a valid partition?
Thank you!

By inspection, put the second row as the sole row in the first partition.

More generally, you can use either an integer linear program or a constraint program to find a valid partition if one exists.
